# How to make a shadow with box-shadow property equal on both sides

Tags: html, ribbon, css

I am trying to make a simple (ribbon like) effect with `box-shadow` property , I have made it on the right side but on the left side the effect is not the same and I cant understand why!
Does somebody have any idea?

My code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj2Ny/1/).

do i have to change something here maybe ?

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this ?

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj2Ny/2/)</kbd>

(I can't see where this seems a ribbon :)

You need to promote the TD to an higher `z-index` (by using `position: relative` to make it works).

Also note that the second parameter in `box-shadow` should be equal to both the sides, it is the (vertical) y-axis.

And using `<div>`s for this kind of stuff is better, `<table>`s should be used for tabular data only.

Comment: i was thinking like this ribbon http://taro-psy.justclick.ru/media/content/taro-psy/burned_orange_ribbon-3333px.png :P, thank you i made the td with the z-index :-1 and it worked , but can you please tell my why i have to make the second parameter the same on both sides ? and why i have to put the position relative ?Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: Because the second parameter is the vertical axis: you want the left to have a left shadow, the right to have a right shadow, but I imagine that you want their shadow at the same height, to be simmetric. Two negative values vs two positive values means `top left` vs `down right`, while you want `top left` vs `top right` (or `bottom left` vs `bottom right`). The `position: relative` is needed to make `z-index` work (because it won't work with the defaul static positioning, and Relative won't affect the page as Fixed and Absolute would do). P.S: nice ribbon, but with CSS only is a pain :D